# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, password, mysql

I know there are similar question already asked here but I had to start a new question as the scenario I have is actually different to the questions already asked.

So here's the problem: I am installing an open source web-based software called 2-Plan Team on a machine connected to the network for all our team members to access. I have set up a database on MySQL for 2-Plan Team as well with the username and password all created. I am still stuck at the installation phase due to an error:

> [Error: Failed to create initial roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weWCE.png)

This error occurs after I try to create the first user which is supposed to be the root/superuser user for the software.

I am actually installing the software using its install.php file through a web browser. I setup a directory called 2plan in the web root folder i.e (/var/www/html). I have created a database for the software in mysql called 2plandb with a username and password.

After following the prompts in the installation process I come across a screen that asks me to create the first user by adding a username and password. When I added the details and clicked the create/add button, the error in the title occurs as well as the error: unable to create initial roles. When I checked the 2plandb in mysql workbench for the first user created, it actually exists in the table however the roles table is empty.

Is it possible that the roles are not created because there is a conflict with the user accounts for the root user of MySQL and the root user for 2-Plan Team thus giving the error in the title?

Have a look at the roles object code here in the `install.php` file:

```
// create the first user
$usr = new user();
$usrid = $usr->add($user, "", 0, $pass);
if (!$usrid)
{
    $template->assign("errortext", "Error: Failed to create first user.");
    $template->display("error.tpl");
    die();
}
// insert default roles
$rolesobj = new roles();

$rootrid = $rolesobj->add("Root", 
    array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1 , "close" => 1), 
    array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
    array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
    array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
    array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1), 
    array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "read" => 1), 
    array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1), 
    array("root" => 1, "add" => 1), 
    array("read" => 1, "write" => 1)
);

$adminrid = $rolesobj->add("Admin", 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1 , "close" => 1),
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "read" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1), 
array("add" => 1), 
array("read" => 1, "write" => 1)
);

$projectrid = $rolesobj->add("Project Manager", 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "read" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1), 
array("add" => 0), 
array("read" => 1, "write" => 1)
);

$userrid = $rolesobj->add("User", 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 0, "close" => 0), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 0, "close" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "close" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1), 
array("add" => 1, "edit" => 1, "del" => 1, "read" => 0), 
array("add" => 0, "edit" => 0, "del" => 0), 
array("add" => 0, "edit" => 0, "del" => 0), 
array("read" => 0, "write" => 0)
);

$clientrid = $rolesobj->add("Client", 
array("add" => 0, "edit" => 0, "del" => 0, "close" => 0), 
array("add" => 0, "edit" => 0, "del" => 0, "close" => 0), 
array("add" => 0, "edit" => 0, "del" => 0, "close" => 0), 
array("add" => 0, "edit" => 0, "del" => 0, "close" => 0), 
array("add" => 0, "edit" => 0, "del" => 0), 
array("add" => 0, "edit" => 0, "del" => 0, "read" => 0), 
array("add" => 0, "edit" => 0, "del" => 0), 
array("add" => 0, "edit" => 0, "del" => 0), 
array("read" => 0, "write" => 0)
);

if (!$rootrid or !$adminrid or !$projectrid or !$userrid or !$clientrid)
{
    $template->assign("errortext", "Error: Failed to create initial roles.");
    $template->display("error.tpl");
    die();
}
$rolesobj->assign($rootrid, $usrid, true);

/*basecamp import, disabled
if (isset($_FILES["importfile"]))
{
    $importer = new importer();
    $myfile = new datei();
    // import basecamp file
    $up = $myfile->upload("importfile", "files/" . CL_CONFIG . "/ics", 0);
    if ($up)
    {
        $importer->importBasecampXmlFile(CL_ROOT . "/files/" . CL_CONFIG . "/ics/$up");
    }
}
*/

$template->display("install3.tpl");
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, are you seeing the error in the title of your post somewhere? It doesn't appear in the body of your question.

Comment: @user62475 apologies. Let me put it this way is the error in the title affecting the roles from being created in the 2-Plan database since there is a conflict between 2 root accounts in mysql?? The install process asks to create the first user which is supposed to be the superuser for the 2-plan software. Does that have a conflict with the root user of mysql therefor generating the error in the title thus affecting the roles from been created??? Hope I am making sense.

Comment: @David Foerster thanks I have edited the post.

Comment: What *exactly* are you doing (or trying to do) to “create the first user which is supposed to be the root/superuser user for the software.” Which commands are you running and at what point does the error message in the title of your question occur?

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks for your response. I have edited my post again to answer your question since my response to your comment was too long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1045(28000) : Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: no )](/q/401449/175814)